# ¿Cómo reflejar en la interfaz gráfica el estado de un item en específico de SharedPreferences cambiado de forma programática?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

Estoy implementando un código según el cual el usuario puede desmarcar una opción en las Preferencias.

Si eso ocurre, lanzo un diálogo con un mensaje al usuario. Si el usuario pulsa en `Confirmar` la preferencia quedaría con ese valor cambiado y la App se cerraría. Eso funciona bien.

Pero si el usuario pulsa en `Cancelar`, yo revierto el valor de la preferencia a `true` de forma programática, pero en la pantalla el cambio no se refleja (la opción aparece como desactivada).

Mi pregunta es: ¿hay algún modo de actualizar **visiblemente** ese elemento, de modo que se active cuando el usuario pulse en `Cancelar` (dado que el valor del item volverá a ser `true` en ese caso)?

O, ¿hay alguna forma de deshacer el último cambio en SharedPreferences y que esto se refleje de inmediato en la interfaz gráfica?

Este es mi código:

```
public class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragmentCompat {

    @Override
    public void onCreatePreferences(Bundle savedInstanceState, String rootKey) {
        setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_general, rootKey);
        Preference acceptTerms = findPreference(PREF_ACCEPT);

        acceptTerms.setOnPreferenceClickListener(
                arg0 -> {
                    showConfirm();
                    return true;
                });
    }

    private void showConfirm() {
        MaterialAlertDialogBuilder materialAlertDialogBuilder = new MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(getActivity());
        materialAlertDialogBuilder.setTitle(DIALOG_LEGAL_TITLE);
        materialAlertDialogBuilder.setMessage(DIALOG_LEGAL_BODY);
        materialAlertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton(DIALOG_LEGAL_OK,
                (dialogInterface, i) -> closeApp());
        materialAlertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton(DIALOG_LEGAL_CANCEL,
                (dialogInterface, i) -> updatePreference());
        materialAlertDialogBuilder.show();
    }

    private void closeApp() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 21) {
            Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()).finishAffinity();
        } else {
            Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()).finishAndRemoveTask();
        }
    }

    /*
       Aquí la preferencia se establece a true internamente
       pero no cambia en la interfaz gráfica
       Mi idea es encontrar una forma de hacer que se active 
       en la interfaz gráfica
    */
    private void updatePreference(){
        SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
        editor.putBoolean(PREF_ACCEPT, true);
        editor.apply();
    }
}
```

Este es el XML de la preferencia:

```
    <SwitchPreference
        android:key="accept_terms"
        android:title="@string/pref_accept_terms"
        android:summary="@string/pref_description_accept_terms"
        android:defaultValue="false"
        />
```

Comment: Si el valor de esa preferencia es `false`, cuando presiones **Confirmar** pasa a `true`, ¿Verdad? Pero, al presionar el botón **Cancelar**, se debe mantener en `false`, ¿O me equivoco?

Comment: @FranqoBalsamo no, es al revés. Esa opción está en `true` (aquí se ve en `false` porque ese es su valor por defecto). Para que se entienda mejor: sin esa opción en `true` el usuario no podrá usar la Aplicación, por tanto, cuando el usuario entra an SharedPreferences la opción estará en `true` siempre. Ahora bien, yo doy al usuario la opción de desactivar esa opción, en cuyo caso, si pulsa en `Confirmar`la opción se queda en `false` y la App se cierra. Eso funciona bien. El problema es si presiona `Cancelar`, la opción vuelve a `true` internamente, pero en la vista se ve como desactivada.

Comment: Todo funciona OK, lo único que no funciona es que yo quiero activarla en la vista, en caso de que el usuario pulse en `Cancelar` en el cuadro de diálogo. Es una cuestión de estética simplemente. Ahora mismo, si el usuario pulsa en `Cancelar` la opción se queda en `true` internamente y si vuelvo a abrir la pantalla aparece activada (`true`), pero yo quiero hacerlo justo después de que pulse `Cancelar`: que la opción se active en la vista.

Comment: Lo voy a repetir para ver si entendí lo que dices, básicamente, cuando presionas **cancelar** tu `switch` (ejemplo) quieres que se vea activada? Si me equivoco, te agradecería que pusieras una imagen/gif para corregir mi idea

Comment: @FranqoBalsamo has entendido correctamente. El switch debe activarse si el usuario presiona `Cancelar`. Como valor sí se pone en `true` (esto ocurre al llamar a `updatePreference()`) pero a la vista del usuario aparece como desactivado (como si tuviera valor `false`).

Answer (score 0):

Lo agrego aquí porque por comentario sería muy largo y complicado de leer, quiero que pruebes hacer esto:

```
private void showConfirm() {
    //resto de tu código
    Preference preferenciaPrueba= findPreference(PREF_ACCEPT);
    materialAlertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton(DIALOG_LEGAL_CANCEL,
            (dialogInterface, i) -> { updatePreference(); ((SwitchPreferenceCompat) preferenciaPrueba).setChecked(true); });
    materialAlertDialogBuilder.show();
}
```

Quiero ver si esto ayuda a lo que buscas, ya que debería tildar tu `Switch` en activado